# C#, MVC4 - EF Linq searches

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

Ok, so i have two questions. The first is, let's say that i have an EF called "EntitiesDefinitions", which holds a data table named "stringData" where each cell is defined as a varchar(100) like so:

```
 ----------------------------------------------
|      | column1   | column2   | column3   | ... | 
----------------------------------------------
| row1 | "1,2,3,4" | "5,6,7,8" | "9,a,b,c" | ... | 
----------------------------------------------
| row2 | "d,e,f,g" | "h,i,j,k" | "l,m,n,o" | ... |
```

Each cell contains 4 pieces of information separated by a comma. So what i would like to know is, if there's a way for me to perform a Linq search for the (as an  example) the 2rd piece of information of every cell in column1?

```
using (EntitiesDefinitions ef = new EntitiesDefinitions())
{
    var v = (from a in ef.stringData where (a.column1... == "e") select a);
}
```

I know I could just make 4 columns per cell (column1_1, column1_2, ...column2_1, column2_2,...), but that wouldn't work if i get a table with +250 original  columns. So is there a way to perform such searches?

The other question is also related to this. Back in ASP.NET i could send queries to my sql using a string like this:

```
var stringSql = "SELECT * FROM" + "stringData" + "WHERE ([" + "column1" + "] =" + "e" + ")" + "ORDER by ["+ "column1" +"] ASC;"
```

Basically, i could define which tables to search for given a string value that represented that property/column. Is there a way to do that with EF linqs?

```
using (EntitiesDefinitions ef = new EntitiesDefinitions())
{
    var v = (from a in ef.stringData where (a.["column1"]... == "e") select a);
}
```

I'm fairly new with MVC and EF, so I would like to know if this is possible.

Comment: 250 columns.... Even before going to C# I'd recommend to "fix" the database by create a view that will unpivot your table into a collection of column_name, column_value - Then use linq to select from the view and do what you need

Comment: Well, 250 original columns, that could extend to N+(250*4) columns; which goes beyond the limit. This is easily solved by creating two parallel tables joined by a common ID column. But I want to keep everything in just one. But i think i found a way to linq search cells with multiple delimiter separators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [Fehintola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1537844/fehintola) suggestion i was able to do more research specific to those subjects and I was able to find a solution for both questions. In case anyone is interested here's what i came up with:

For the first question, while is not elegant, we can encapsulate data inside in specific characters/delimiters and then we can process search results in nested searches. For example:

```
using (EntitiesDefinitions ef = new EntitiesDefinitions())
{
    //Data could look like";1;*2*&3&#4#"
    var v = (from a in ef.stringData where select a); //to store the table
    v = c.Where(f => f.column1.Contains("*2*")) //look for the second value
    v = x.Where(f => f.column1.Contains("#4.3#"));//look for the forth value

    //Do some other stuff...like sending the data to a table
}
```

For the Second question, you can make raw sql queries like this:

```
string sqlExample = @"SELECT VALUE a FROM ef.stringData AS a WHERE (a.column1 == '*2*')";
var test = ef.CreateQuery<stringData>(sql).AsQueryable();
```

This was you can just have variables placed in the sqlExample string to build your query dynamically and you'll get back a IQueryable object you can use to, for example, pass into a table.

I hope this helps someone in the future and thanks to everyone that provided suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question you can try this out if u sure its always not null:

```
   var res = ef.stringData.Where(c => c.column1.Split(',')[1] == "e")
```

And for the Second Question where you type "ef.stringData" the name of the table you are querying is "stringData" there is no other way to specify the table name or only if you want to write raw sql queries in EF.

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution you suggested for the first question returned "The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities". However, I found a workaround it that, albeit not elegant, does a similar function to the split. For the second question, i see, so you are suggesting i look for way to write raw sql queries in EF?

Comment: Okay Cool. Try to write raw sql queries if you really prefer to write it.